# Change the colour of the x icon for the ng-multiselect-dropdown component

Tags: angular, ng-multiselect-dropdown

I'm currently using angular v9 and I have implemented a multiselect dropdown button using ng-multiselect-dropdown, after trying to change the style of the selected items, I can't seem to be able to change the colour of the x Icon.

How can I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Override the `x` icon's color globally.
2. Override the `x` icon's color locally.

#### 1. Override `x` icon's color globally:

In the root style.css

```css
.multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn .selected-item a {
  color: red;
}
```

#### 2. Override `x` icon's color locally:

In the same component's css file.

```css
:host ::ng-deep .multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn .selected-item a {
  background-color: red;
}
```